# Как правильно сделать парсер?

Tags: php, парсер, синтаксический-анализ

Задача написать парсер. На первой странице указаны номера документов и ссылки на подробную информацию по документу. По каждой из указанных ссылок тоже нужно собрать некоторые данные. При обработке цикла foreach вылетает ошибка сервера

> Ошибка 502, ошибка шлюза. Вероятно, ресурс сейчас перегружен запросами
>   или на нём присутствует ошибка. Попробуйте обратиться к ресурсу чуть
>   позже.

Как правильно написать парсер? Как сделать, чтобы страницы грузились постепенно?

```
    include 'simple_html_dom.php';  
    $html = str_get_html(addslashes(file_get_html('http://')));  
    $html1=$html->find('div[id="\"ctl00_ctl00_phWorkZone_dataPanel\""]',0)->plaintext;  
    $t=strpos($html1, '/data');  
    $t=$t-4;  
    $html2=substr($html1,0,$t);  
    $ar = explode("row>", $html2);  



    foreach($ar as $val){  
        $ib=strpos($val, 'purchID');    
        $if=strpos($val, '/purchID>');    
        $cb=strpos($val, 'purchCode');  
        $cf=strpos($val, '/purchCode>'); 



    $i=substr($val,$ib+8,$if-16);  
    $c=substr($val,$cb+11,$cf-51);  

    if ($i!=''){  
        echo '<br><a href="http://?id='.$i.'">Au#'.$c.'</a>';  
        $doc=str_get_html(addslashes(file_get_html('http://?id='.$i)));  
        $doc_link=$doc->find('tr[newinfolink]')->find('td')->find('a')->plaintext;  
        echo 'doc'.$doc_link;  
    }  
}
```

Comment: а вы уверенны, что страницы не постепенно загружаются?

Comment: возмонжо, я новичок. Суть проблемы в ошибке сервера "Ошибка 502, ошибка шлюза. Вероятно, ресурс сейчас перегружен запросами или на нём присутствует ошибка. Попробуйте обратиться к ресурсу чуть позже." Если убрать из цикла сканинг следующей страницы, то все работает нормально. Типа вот так:
    if ($i!=''){  
    echo '<br><a href="http://?id='.$i.'">Au#'.$c.'</a>';  
    }

Comment: используйте cURL

Comment: а если между парсингом страниц вставить sleep  на секунд так 20? Похоже на защиту от ddos'a (а может своими запросами Вы его и сделали).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте `cURL`, там есть `timeout` как минимум, да и обрабатывать ошибки можно удобно ну и в случае ошибки отправить повторный запрос.

ps; по поводу 502 ошибки - напишите гневное письмо владельцу сайта, что его север не позволяет парсить страницу :)))